Marketing api: get media files from asset library by business Id
I'm trying to get creative folders using Business Id as it described in docs
/{business-id}/creative_folders

But I get an error:
'(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (creative_folders) on node type (Business)'

How to get folders/images/videos by business id which available on https://business.facebook.com/asset_library/business_creatives
